# solve equation with power and square root at the same time

Tags: real-analysis

i find it quite difficult to solve this simple equation, you find examples for sub-problems, but i did not find for both problems a solution (convex and concave functions):

$(1+0.05)^t -1$ = $\sqrt(t)*0.1$

with Excel, i can prove that $t$ = 3.52785480404031, but i am not able to solve this step by step, so that i rearange the formula to $t$ = ....

[f(1) = f(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up63O.png)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2B0.05%29%5Et-1%3D0.1*%5Csqrt%28t%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(t)=a^t -\frac 1 {10} \sqrt t-1 \qquad \text{with} \quad a=\frac{21}{20}$$ To mka it more pleasant, let $t=x^2$ and consider
$$g(x)=a^{x^2}-\frac{x}{10}-1$$

By inspection $g(2)$ is positive. Now, taking logarithms, consider
$$h(x)=x^2\log(a)-\log \left(1+\frac{x}{10}\right)$$ and expand as series around $x=2$
$$h(x)=\left(4 \log (a)-\log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)\right)+(x-2) \left(4 \log
   (a)-\frac{1}{12}\right)+(x-2)^2 \left(\log
   (a)+\frac{1}{288}\right)+O\left((x-2)^3\right)$$
Solve the quadratic in $(x-2)$

$$x=\frac{2 \left(7+6 \sqrt{576 \log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right) \log (a)-104 \log (a)+1+2
   \log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}\right)}{288 \log (a)+1}$$ Replace $a$ by its value t get
$$x=1.878261989 \implies t=x^2 =3.527868099$$ which is not too bad.

Comment: i find it quite complex, because there is no simple solution for t.

Comment: @RDummy. It is just inspection and a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

From your equation
$$ln(1.05)t=ln(1+(0.1)\sqrt{t})$$
If we assume that $(0.1)\sqrt{t}$ is small,
$ln(1+x)\approx x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ hence we get
$$ln(1.05)t=0.1\sqrt{t}-0.005t$$
$$(ln(1.05)+0.005)t=0.1\sqrt{t}$$
$$t=(\frac{0.1}{ln(1.05)+0.005})^2\approx 3.46$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%5Cfrac%7B0.1%7D%7Bln%281.05%29%2B0.005%7D%29%5E2

we needed cubic term.